# how to supply only second optional parameter in php?

Tags: php, function, option-type

I have this function:

```
function generic_notify($subject = "notify triggered", $message = "<p>Generic notification</p>", $to = "pavel.janicek@mydomain.mydomain"){
    EDD()->emails->send( $to, $subject, $message );
}
```

In some cases, I am completely fine to just call `generic_notify();` and know that some function was called, because the above will send me mail.

In other cases, I would like to just change message, or just subject or send it to other email.

If I wanted to just change the message, is it possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. :(

Comment: I was afraid of that answer. I will refactor my function a bit so that message is first, because that is the most probable to be changed

Comment: Indeed. There have been a couple of RFCs for this specific functionality, but they didn't go through iirc.

Comment: nope you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't but if I were you just put a condition inside that function

```
function generic_notify($subject = null, $message = null, $to = null){

    // your default value
    $defaultSubject = "notify triggered";
    $defaultMessage = "<p>Generic notification</p>";
    $defaultTo = "pavel.janicek@mydomain.mydomain";

    $to = (!empty($to)) ? $to : $defaultTo;
    $subject = (!empty($subject)) ? $subject : $defaultSubject;
    $message = (!empty($message)) ? $message : $defaultMessage;

        echo "Subject: ".$subject ."<br>";
        echo "Message: ".$message ."<br>";
        echo "TO: ".$to."<br>";
}

// if you want not to change all the default parameter just leave blank
generic_notify();

// if you want to change the default parameter just put a value that is not null on it
generic_notify(null, '<p>Change Message</p>', null);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/827905)

Comment: This is seriously cool workaround. I will stick around with little refactoring, but have my accept and upvote because this is general solution to the problem